# __setattr__ to prohibit changes to instance/self variables?

Tags: python, class, setattr

I have a class Fraction whose **init** creates the instance variables `self.num = num` and `self.denom=denom`:

```
    def __init__(self,num=0,denom=1):
        assert isinstance(num, int), "Numerator and denominator must be an integer"
        assert isinstance(denom, int), "Numerator and denominator must be an integer"
        assert denom != 0, "Denominator cannot be 0."
        self.num = num
        self.denom = denom
```

and I'm trying to write its `__setattr__` method to prohibit changes to the instance variables once they have been initialized by raising a NameError:

```
    def __setattr__(self,name,value):
        if name not in Fraction.__dict__:
            self.__dict__[name] = value
        else:
            raise NameError
```

From printing `Fraction.__dict__`, I can see that the dict contains Fractions methods, rather than num,denom and their respective values. So I then tried to do: `if name not in Fraction().__dict__:` and I ended up with a infinite recursion error. How can I access the dictionary that contains the instance variables?

Comment: It sounds like you wanted `self.__dict__` in the `if`, not only in the assignment later.

Comment: The members `num` and `denum` are bound to an instance of your class. Thus, you have to use `self.__dict__` instead of `Fraction.__dict__`.

Comment: You could also use drozen dataclasses.

Comment: Ahh, I can't believe I overlooked that. The marked answer and these comments both solve my problem in different ways. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `__slots__` instead to limit attributes to only those you want.

https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#slots

> `__slots__` allow us to explicitly declare data members (like properties) and deny the creation of `__dict__` and `__weakref__` (unless explicitly declared in `__slots__` or available in a parent.)

> [...]
> Without a `__dict__` variable, **instances cannot be assigned new variables not listed in the `__slots__` definition**. Attempts to assign to an unlisted variable name raises `AttributeError`. [...]

So basically in your class add this, preferably somewhere at the top (just after `class` line and before init):

```
__slots__ = 'num', 'denom'
```

And remove your setattr :)

Comment: I see. This is a lot simpler, as well. Thank you.

Comment: Beware. Slots are not intended to prevent adding new attributes to objects but are an optimization feature - read official Python doc about that point. Specifically subclasses will get a `__dict__` special attribute which will allow dynamic creation of new attributes.

Comment: @SergeBallesta The doc link is already in my answer, I only quoted parts relevant to the question. :) But as to what you mention, from those same docs: `The action of a __slots__ declaration is not limited to the class where it is defined. __slots__ declared in parents are available in child classes. However, child subclasses will get a __dict__ and __weakref__ unless they also define __slots__ (which should only contain names of any additional slots).`